# Doctrinal bias control by users who do not like questions or cannot answer them

Tags: discussion

BHSE appears to be unduly controlled by some who do not like specific questions or have difficulty answering questions, and shut valid questions down by using such classifications as - 'opinion based' question or 'some in the community do not like your question' and stopping them from asking more.

If the questions relate to the bible and refer to the passages of the bible - why should there be an issue?  The point is not whether people *like* questions but should simply be about analysing the bible. The likelihood is that there will be different opinions - or is the expectation that we all have to have the SAME OPINION?

Comment: It would be helpful for discussion if you provided some examples

Comment: Well my last question (1 question) 4 days ago and I have now been stopped from asking questions.  previous questions about a month ago.  The questions are not even my opinion, passages from the bible for clarification / analysis.

Comment: It is true that there is, as you state, 'clear control on the site'. And it is true that the community influences and processes the asking of questions. This is a necessity and is also an aspect of the Stack Exchange model. Otherwise the site would rapidly deteriorate and the objective (of providing a database of referenced information) would not be realised. We all take part in this procedure. Nobody is singled out for adverse treatment. The rules of the site are laid out clearly in the Tour and the Help.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes - to run efficiently - that's clearly not the control im talking about.  maybe you can explain to me why I have been stopped from answering a question - when the last one was 4 days ago and the one before over 1 month ago. What issue did you have for my last question? It clear you have had an issue with me from the beginning because you do not like my questions - but I reiterate all related to passages from the bible.

Comment: @anothertheory Could you please give me the link to the incident you refer to as 'I have been stopped from answering . . .'. As to questions, every question asked on this site relates to the bible, but the community (myself included) expresses a vote in regard to the applicability of biblical questions to the hermeneutic aspect of this particular site.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45183/habakuk-chapter-3-verse-2-4-holy-one-from-mount-paran-selah-who-does-this-p

Comment: @anothertheory I cannot see any problems when I follow that link. You have asked a question, you have been up-voted, and you have received two well-written and substantial answers. This is a perfect example of how the site should work.

Comment: so why have i been stopped from asking another question?  On the basis that 'some people do not like my questions', which i submit shouldn't make a difference if the question relates to passages from the bible.

Comment: Do you have many deleted questions? The automatic question ban takes them into account too.

Comment: lol 'lets not kid ourselves', im sure your well aware or everything!

Comment: @curiousdannii   Veterans of the site know how to influence the "automated" responses to downvotes and closed questions.   All it takes is a group of those who have enough privileges to work together and the results are predictable.   Fortunately there are apparently some on the site who recognize this and work to mitigate this behavior.   That's what helped me.

Answer (score 1):

**How BHSE is supposed to work**

The StackExchange format relies on building up a community of experienced users who understand the design and intent of the site and its scope. BHSE has a tightly defined scope which can be difficult to understand for users who have not really thought about hermeneutics before, or who don't take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/tour). Perhaps the biggest barrier to new users getting off to a good start is experienced users not giving sufficient feedback, or welcoming them to begin with. This should feel like a community, not just a "system".

There are various *Review Queues* which experienced users access in order to check noteworthy site events and 'nudge' the flow of new Questions and Answers in a healthy direction. When this system is followed well, new users should receive good quality feedback wherever they are experiencing issues.

---

**How experienced users commonly fail to achieve this**

For those with access to the Review Queues, too few really help with the 'First Posts' category, or click idly through posts that don't have obvious problems without really welcoming users or considering what guidance may benefit them. When too many experienced users 'click through' these review queues and just do the bare minimum, this can leave new users feeling discouraged, as they don't know what the actual problems are with their Questions or Answers.

If just a handful more of us were to meaningfully engage in this from time to time, the overall 'feel' of the site to new users would vastly improve.

---

**How some new users experience it (initially)**

With that said, I think that you've misinterpreted the events, as have some others who have responded here:

> "All it takes is a group of those who have enough privileges to work
>   together"

It's easy to vastly over-estimate the desire of experienced site users to behave like this, as well as over-estimating their willingness to co-ordinate for these types of outcomes. Most new users take feedback well and learn to ask better questions and give better answers. An initial negative-feedback loop frustrates many of us, but as we persevere and improve, it then becomes a positive-feedback loop as our approaches improve.

In practice, some users take many more conversations before they're willing to accept feedback or learn more about the SE format, or indeed the scope of BHSE. All users (new and old) have biases, but it should always be possible to use the site properly from almost any background (Christian, Jewish, other theist, Agnostic, Atheist or any subgroup) without undue penalisation. After all, the wider range of peer-reviewed literature on hermeneutics is crafted by a similarly varied group of individuals, and it should be safe to assume most experienced users are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing.   It's an eye opener.   I won't  view answers on the internet from SE the same way ever again.    Views that are not from the mainstream Christian POV are sometimes suppressed.

There are some here that get very picky about rules when they don't like the content and don't have a ready answer.

Comment: And yet "non mainstream Christian POV" users like Dick Harfield and Ruminator, and Jews such as (I think, based on their MY rep) "b a" and רבות מחשבות all have many well received questions and answers. This isn't to say that many people haven't had a poor reception here, and many poor answers from traditional "Christian" perspectives do get upvotes they don't deserve, unfortunately. There's a lot we can do to make this site better: write clear questions and answers that explain and justify their conclusions, and flag and downvote poor questions and answers.

Comment: @curiousdannii   I got downvoted for merely expressing my opinion and sharing my experience.   What does that tell you?

Comment: It means I think you're wrong. There's no suppression of views.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I don't downvote merely because I think someone is wrong.  I downvote for dishonesty.

Comment: You're free to vote how you like. But on Meta sites downvotes for disagreement are very common.

Comment: @Thomas Pearne - thank you for your comments. basically you've **Hit the Nail on the head** I’m not familiar with the workings, yet it’s clear to me that a ‘few’ are working together and causing me issues since the beginning because they do not like my questions. Albeit all related to passages from the bible.  I’m not even coming from particular perspective.  I’m only interested in Text evidence.  Down votes should **NOT** be because you disagree with someone, only for badly constructed / weak questions. cont...

Comment: .  I’m actually more interested when people disagree with my reading of the text providing a different explanation, best way to learn see all sides of the story! I thought that's what it is all about learning the truth from the Bible.
Thomas I hope you do not get more problems because you aired your opinion.

Comment: @anothertheory I'd be more sympathetic if you hadn't posted complete non-questions like [this one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/44580/2757). Meanwhile [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/44598/2757) is not about the interpretation of a passage, but systematic theology (probably belonging at Christianity.SE) and is also very poorly written, lacking context.

Comment: @curiousdannii how can **this one** very important passage sign from Jesus as 'Jonah was' be a non-question?  & **this question** refers to the relevant passages whats the problem?  Apart from it may challenge your view.  You should also note that these questions are over a month old.  I still haven't been informed why I have been stopped from asking more questions, when the last question 6 days old appears to be fine?

Comment: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/256282)

Comment: Where is the question mark in your post about Jonah and Jesus?

Comment: @curiousdannii - Lol is that the best you can do? (you would have noticed I made sure of the question mark).  Obviously, no one wants to explain why i was stopped from asking questions, only **one conclusion**

Comment: What question mark did you make sure of? You didn't ask a question, punctuation or not.

Comment: the question was - is that the best you can do?

Comment: When your posts are so poorly received on so many sites you might like to consider your own stubborn refusal to learn from the advice of others about how to write good questions. You can't blame it all on theological bias for sites like Philosophy. I've said enough. Hope you'll be willing to listen some day.

Comment: @curiousdannii your opinion, **but no substance** - nothing to learn from that